# Change fixed background-image on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, addeventlistener, onscroll

As mentioned in the title I am trying to change a background-image on scroll and adding a nice transition with ease.

The background-image should be fixed and stays in position. The content is moving.

Any ideas?

I managed to get the image changed but the transition is not working.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var backgroundContainer = document.querySelector('.background-container');

    // Add more images if you like.
    var backgroundImages = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg'];


    var currentImageIndex = 0;

    // Set first background image
    backgroundContainer.classList.add('background-image-1');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        // Check if you have scrolled to the top.
        var scrolledToTop = window.scrollY === 0;

        // Change backgroundclass
        if (scrolledToTop) {
            currentImageIndex = 0;
            backgroundContainer.classList.remove('background-image-2');
            backgroundContainer.classList.add('background-image-1');
        } else {
            currentImageIndex = 1;
            backgroundContainer.classList.remove('background-image-1');
            backgroundContainer.classList.add('background-image-2');
        }
      
    backgroundContainer.style.transition = 'background-image 1.5s ease';      
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for this behavior ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: Your JavaScript code is mostly fine, but you don't need to set the transition style in JavaScript. Your CSS should handle this. Add `transition: background-image 1.5s ease;` to the `.background-container` class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only CSS properties which take decimal values are [animatable](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.php). So `opacity` is animatable, but `background-image` is not.

Simplest solution is probably to stack several images and animate their opacity.